# Databse utf8mb4_unicode_ci not save full emojies

Tags: mysql, database, collections, emoji, utf8mb4

I use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for my tables

But this collection not save all emojies and replace with `????`

For example  save correct but  replace with `????`

Also I use `utf8mb4_bin` but not work

Answer (score 0):

I find answer

I added `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` to mysqli and work fine

Comment: Better is to use `mysqli::set_charset('utf8mb4');`